# Superman has the strength of how many men?

Tags: dc, superman, powers

Like 100? 1000? And was it said anywhere in the comics? (The modern age)

Comment: What kind of man are we talking here? Like Andy Dick or Dwayne Johnson?

Comment: ∞ [hopefully you can see that.]

Comment: normal humans..

Comment: [Quintillions, if I recall correctly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_2OCLpLC1s).

Comment: Which version/era?

Comment: the modern age...

Comment: @MeghGandhi edit that into your question

Comment: The answer is, it depends. He became gradually stronger during the fifties, sixties and seventies. After that, it seems to have gone downhill a bit. He's still very strong though.

Comment: As many as the plot needs.

Comment: His strength is displayed inconsistently within the same comic series', let alone in the "modern era" whenever that is supposed to be. Unless you can define the question more closely, this is far too broad to answer sensibly.

Comment: He's [as fast as ten fast men](http://tick.wikia.com/wiki/The_Running_Guy)!

Answer (score 6):

Superman has been stated to be, in the 1941 cartoon,

> More powerful than a locomotive

In 1941, the ALCO RS-1 was released. It had 1000 horsepower. This is equivalent to 745,699 watts.  The average human can output 100 watts when cycling.

Thus, Superman can be said to be stronger than 7457 men.

More recently, All-Star Superman lifted 200 quintillion tons (1.81437e23 kg) easily.  The average man can bench press 135 pounds, putting All-Star Superman at 2.962963e21 humans strong.

Comment: OP is looking for info regarding the modern age superman.

Comment: Ugh, changed during my answer.  Re-calculating.

Comment: The average man can only bench press 135 pound? Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: For the exponentially impaired: Superman is estimated to be as strong as 2.9 sextillion Humans. A completely meaningless number in the minds of modern man, [almost impossible to imagine.](http://www.metafilter.com/98112/Thats-a-big-number)

Comment: http://www.livestrong.com/article/380767-how-much-weight-can-the-average-man-lift/
The source for my claim that the average man can only benchpress 135 pounds.

Comment: I think the number would be better expressed in long form. He is stronger than 2,900,000,000,000,000,000,000 humans.

Comment: I think it could also be made more poignant when we remember that this mass is only 3% of the earth's mass. Superman can't carry the world on his shoulders, but he can almost carry Australia.